# Is it possible to add an URL to InLineKeyboardButton?

Tags: python, url, telegram

What I want to do is to open up an URL link upon the button press. Is this possible though?

`bot.answer_callback_query` ? im not sure

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        tt = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="1", callback_data="1")

elif call.data == "1"
```

Can someone help please?

Answer (score 2):

Use *url* instead of *callback_data*:

```
keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard.row(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="1", url="http://www.rbc.ru")
)
```

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton